# Are there global variables in grunt?

Tags: gruntjs

While trying to do some kind of generic grunt task i got stuck while accessing variables/options.

I need some kind of global variable or something similar.
It seems I have overlooked something.

If I run `grunt sassCompile:myprojectFolder`, everything works fine 
while `grunt sassWatch:myprojectFolder` does not.

I run it in verbose mode and it seems **projectPath** is empty while compass is being called by watch.

compass options (from verbose output):

**sassCompile**: `config="projectRoot/myprojectFolder/config.rb" ...`

**sassWatch**: `config="config.rb" ...`

This is the Gruntfile.js is used for testing:

What I am doing wrong?

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    module.exports = function (grunt) {
        grunt.initConfig({
            compass: {
                dev: {
                    options: {
                        config: "<%= projectPath %>config.rb",
                        basePath: "<%= projectPath %>",
                        specify: ["<%= projectPath %>src/sass/style*.scss","!**/*ie*.scss"],
                        bundleExec: true
                    }
                }
            },
            watch: {
                css: {
                    files: ['<%= projectPath %>../**/*.scss'],
                    tasks: ['compass']
                }
            }
        });
        grunt.registerTask('sassCompile', 'compass', function (project) {
            grunt.config('projectPath', 'projectRoot/' + project + '/');
            grunt.task.run('compass');
        });
        grunt.registerTask('sassWatch', 'watch', function (project) {
            grunt.config('projectPath', 'projectRoot/' + project + '/');
            grunt.task.run('watch');
        });

        grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
        grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-compass');
    };
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely an interesting approach you have there – it took me a while to understand what is going on.

What happens when run `grunt sassWatch:myprojectFolder` is that the `watch` task gets started with the `projectPath` you supplied after the colon, *but*, when `watch` detects a change it runs the `compass` task without the configuration.

That is because `grunt-contrib-watch` runs it's tasks by starting a new grunt process. You *could* run the tasks inside the same process by using `options: { spawn: false }`, but that seems to be discouraged.

I would suggest you try this:

```
watch: {
    css: {
        files: ['<%= projectPath %>../**/*.scss'],
        tasks: ['sassCompile:<%= projectPath %>']
    }
}
```

That way `watch` will run `sassCompile:myprojectFolder` in the spawned grunt process, making sure the configuration gets transferred to the `compass` task.

Comment: thank you for the tip regarding processes.
i will run all with span false for now.
(the task will be much bigger then the sample at the end)

Answer (score 0):

At the grunt page there is a [section about global variables](http://gruntjs.com/frequently-asked-questions#globals-and-configs), but they won't work across multiple processes.

It would be possible to start a new async process by hand and handover the needed variables.

You could take a look at [here](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-concurrent) and possible extend it to accept parameters for the new processes.